# Successive calls to UIViewController's presentViewController method

Tags: ios, asynchronous, presentmodalviewcontroller

I recently encountered a hair-pulling situation in my iOS app, where I was trying to successively dismiss one presented `UIViewController` from my window's rootViewController, using:

```
[rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL]
```

and present another one shortly thereafter (in another method, incidentally), with:

```
UIViewController *vc2 = [[[MyViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];
[rootViewController presentViewController:vc2 animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Problem was, I could never get the second view controller to show up.  Turns out, as near as I can tell, `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` needs that asynchronous block of "completion" time to pass, before `presentViewController:animated:completion:` will work properly again.  This fact is not directly documented in [Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html), from what I can tell.

The solution I came up with was to wrap the dismissal with a method that specifies the selector you would want to call afterwards, like so:

```
- (void)dismissViewController:(UIViewController *)presentingController
                   postAction:(SEL)postDismissalAction
{
    [presentingController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                             completion:^{
                                                            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:postDismissalAction
                                                                                   withObject:nil
                                                                                waitUntilDone:NO];
                                                         }];
}
```

And then I would call:

```
[self dismissViewController:self.window.rootViewController
                 postAction:@selector(methodForNextModalPresentation)];
```

Anyway, I wanted to post, as I looked around and hadn't seen anyone with this particular problem, so I thought it might be useful for people to understand.  And also, I wanted to verify that I'm not hacking a solution that has a better design pattern for resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of clarity. are you saying that this code doesn't work?

```
[myRootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [myRootViewController pushViewController:newController animated:YES];
}];
```

Comment: I believe that code should work.  My example was using presentViewController as the follow-up call, but I would assume you would encounter the same problem with your code if, instead of taking action in the completion block, you did:

`[myRootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
[myRootViewController pushViewController:newController animated:YES];`